# Why there's no "init" command in dotnet nuget?

Tags: .net, nuget

I have 2 `NuGet`s on my Windows PC. One came with the .NET, the other one is manually downloaded.
The one that runs without dotnet has the `init` command, the other one has not.

What's up with that? Which version is the proper one? And what is the proper (and fastest) way to create a local repo with the versioned file system? I have loose packages in a directory. I use the downloaded nuget with the `init` command. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: Hmm, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-init says it's equal to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package on each package, is that what you mean?

Comment: We (NuGet team) have the same 24 hours in a day as everyone else, and even if all new requests and bug reports stopped today, we have enough work for at least 5 years. So it's all just a question of prioritisation. Probably an unsatisfying answer, but it is what it is. For what it's worth, I would absolutely love to port all remaining commands from nuget.exe to the dotnet cli and deprecate nuget.exe. It's an awful part of our build process and depends on the deprecated/abandoned ilmerge. But I have a lot of other work, which is more useful, so that gets my time.

Comment: @zivkan Thank you, that completely answers my question and it's what I needed to know. I'm just finishing my toolkit's build system and I needed to decide on local repository building tool. For now I'm going with the current nuget.exe, and nuget.* packages for my internal repo management.